# Updating CSS variable with JavaScript not happening at runtime

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I have an odd issue. I am attempting to set a CSS variable and change this dynamically on page load.

It works fine in my rudimentary jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/jw6t0krm/

The basic code is:

```
const colours = ['#ee4800','#60c600','#00ffff','#ff7f00','#ff6ccc','#848382','#d2dd26'];
const rndColour = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--selection-background", colours[rndColour]);
```

My app is more complex in using transpiling, so my `setColourFunction` looks like this:

```
const colours = ['#ee4800','#60c600'...]; // same as previous array

const rndColour = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);

const setRandomColour = () => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
        '--selection-background',
        colours[rndColour]
    );
};

export { setRandomColour };
```

Then, in my main app, I am importing like so:

```
import { setRandomColour } from './js/randomColours';

$(document).ready(() => {
   if (DOM.classList.contains('high-contrast')) {
        setRandomColour();
   }
}
```

In the browser, the background colour is set as a pink tone by default (which is one of the items inside the colour array). If I hover over the scrollbar or click the navigation, the scrollbar changes colour to the correct value in the variable. I assumed this might be some Chrome bug, but the jsfiddle seems to work fine.

You can see an example of the live app here: https://studiomalarkey.co.uk/

[image]

At one time, I did have a reference to my minified script using the defer method, and thought this might be the issue, but I have removed that property now.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: So what should happen and what is happening instead? Should the scrollbar color update immediately, but it only updates on hover or on click?

Comment: The css variable should be updated to the new colour, and it appears to be if you check the inspector (see image in post) but it is only changing after some event. But the scrollbar is still showing in the default pink colour. It should just run on page load (I am not binding it to any specific JS event)

Comment: Looks like a Browser-Bug. You could try applying those styles not to the body, but to an inner wrapper. Maybe it'll work better.

Comment: Let me try other browsers. I was trying to set it inside the open nav panel also. Will test that next.

Comment: Are you certain that that code gets entered?

Comment: Yes, the variable is being set, you can tell in the inspector. It works perfectly in Safari, but not Edge, or Firefox (but it is vendor specific code). I also tried wrapping it in a short setTimeout function. No dice. So I think this is a browser glitch

Comment: OK I have tried a few hacks, and not keen on what I have working, but I initialise two quick clicks on the navigation to open and close in milliseconds, and it seems to work.